# Memory leak by AttachInfo.mRootCallbacks reported by LeakCanary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) library to troubleshoot a memory leak of my activity.
After fixing several issues I got this logcat output :

> - com.MyPackage.activities.MyActivity has leaked:
> - GC ROOT com.MyPackage.MyView.mAttachInfo
> - references android.view.View$AttachInfo.mRootCallbacks
> - references android.view.ViewRootImpl.mContext
> - leaks com.MyPackage.activities.MyActivity instance

1. I have no idea what this reference mean. The view is keeping a reference to the activity which prevents it from being GCed? When and how should I handle it?
2. I used [Eclipse memory analyze tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) tool and found that there are actually no instances of my activity alive. Does that make sense?

Also opened this as an [issue](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/210) for canary.

---

Edit 1 : relevant implementation :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     MyView.InteractionCallbacks interactionCallback = new InteractionCallbackImplementation(
     mNewView = new MyView(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
     LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                                                                                          Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     ViewGroup fragmentLayout = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
     fragmentLayout.addView(mNewView, 0);
}

public static class InteractionCallbackImplementation implements MyView.InteractionCallbacks {

        WeakReference<MyFragment> frag;
        public InteractionCallbackImplementation(MyFragment myFragment){
            frag = new WeakReference<myFragment>(myFragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void partsSelected(long[] parts) {
               // ...
        }
}
```

The view :
Is a part of external jar which handles gl rendering. has a reference to the fragment.

```
public class MyView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {
     private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
          this.getHandler().post(runnable);
     }
}
```

What I know is that when I leave the activity :

1. The activity is destroyed and there are no instances of the activity anymore.
2. The fragment is destroyed.
3. The view is detached.

So why would the canary library claim that - there’s a leaked reference?

When and how should a view lose it's reference to it's context?

Comment: Hi Dror, please add some source code for MyActivity and MyView + all relevant so that we might be able to see if there is an actual issue there or not

Comment: Added the things I thought relevant, and the main question that bugs me at the end.